# Fedora 38: DNF update requires user@1000.service to be restarted

Tags: fedora, dnf

Today there was an update in Fedora 38:
[image]

After the update completed, I checked if a reboot or a service needs to be restarted with the following DNF commands:

After the update completed, I checked whether a reboot or service restart is required using the following DNF commands:

`sudo dnf needs-restarting -r`

```
No core libraries or services have been updated since boot-up.
Reboot should not be necessary.
```

`sudo dnf needs-restarting -s`

I receive an output showing `user@1000.service`.

What is this service? It appears to be related to the currently logged-on user.

Instead of restarting the service, should I simply log out and log back in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user@1000.service` is the user manager instance for the logged-in user with UID 1000, i.e. the system process that manages the `systemctl --user` services for that user. See `man user@.service` for more details.

You are entirely correct: logging out and back in would be exactly what is needed at this point.